# How to specify a default primary key with no auto increment

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
class Sizes < ActiveRecord::Migration
      def self.up
        create_table :sizes do |t|
          t.integer  :size,     :null => false
        end
      end

      def self.down
        drop_table :sizes
      end
end    

class Sizes < ActiveRecord::Migration
      def self.up
        Size.create(:id => 1, :size => 5)
        Size.create(:id => 2, :size => 10)
      end

      def self.down
        Size.delete_all
      end
end
```

While trying to populate the db using the command `rake db:migrate` and i got the following output

```
select * from sizes;
id          size
1           5
2           10
```

After I rollback the entire tables from db using the command called `rake db:rollback`. Once again I re-populated the db and now it seems to be the following

```
select * from sizes;
id          size
3           5
4           10
```

I don't want the primary key to change, how do I stop specifying the auto increment capability or specify the ability to associate a hard-coded primary key id, so that it remains the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
create_table(:id => false) do |t|
  t.integer :own_id, :options => 'PRIMARY KEY'
end
```

Hope this helps

Comment: It doesn't work for you, but you accepted the answer :(

Answer (score 0):

`rake db:rollback` will take you one step back, which in your case will delete the sizes you created (1 => 5, 2 => 10)

You could go one more step back which will drop the table and then run migration's again, recreating the table and the data.

Alternately if you'd only like to go back one step then you can execute some custom sql in `self.down` method

```
def self.down
  Size.delete_all
  execute <<-SQL 
    ALTER TABLE Sizes AUTO_INCREMENT=0 
  SQL
end
```

You can also try

```
create_table :sizes, :options => "auto_increment = 0" do |t|
  ...
end
```